# Как выбрать атрибут из xml?

Tags: php, xml

Нужно в цикле делать выборку атрибутов из xml-файла.
Но при обращении к атрибуту возвращает `SimpleXmlElement`
Как получить непосредственно значение атрибута `name`?

```
$citiesXml  = simplexml_load_file( 'cities.xml' );
$city = $citiesXml->region[5]->city->attributes()->name
```

В результате `$city` содержит `SimpleXmlElement` а не само значение атрибута `name`.

```
SimpleXMLElement::__set_state(array(
   0 => 'город',
))
```

Как это правильно сделать?

Структура xml примерно такая:

```
<regions>
    <region name="Область">
        <city lat="45.055" lon="34.6333" name="Город" />
    </region>
    ...
</regions>
```

Цикл такой:

```
foreach($citiesXml as $idarea){
    foreach($idarea->city->attributes() as $idcity => $name){

    }
}
```